# Piping input to script not working properly

Tags: bash

This is my shell script (automate_test.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -i ball1.rtf container
cp -i ball2.rtf container
cp -i ball3.rtf container
```

This is the input file for this script (in_test.txt):

```
n
y
n
```

And, I am executing this command :

```
cat "in_test.txt" | ./automate_test.sh
```

Folder named "container" already contains files named "ball1.rtf","ball2.rtf" and "ball3.rtf" Expected behaviour is that only ball2 should be overwritten. But output is as follows :

```
overwrite container/ball1.rtf? (y/n [n]) not overwritten
overwrite container/ball2.rtf? (y/n [n]) not overwritten
overwrite container/ball3.rtf? (y/n [n]) not overwritten
```

Comment: [The POSIX spec for `cp`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html) requires it to read answers to the prompt from stdin, so where's using `cat` is a little suboptimal, the approach as a whole should work. Are you sure your file has UNIX rather than DOS newlines?

Comment: Try making it `printf '%s\n' n y n | ./automate_test.sh`, so we know the exact byte-for-byte contents and can't get thrown off by BOMs, encoding types, DOS newlines, etc..

Comment: ...and in the future, `<in_test.txt ./automate_test.sh` or the equivalent `./automate_test.sh <in_test.txt` is more efficient than using `cat in_test.txt | ./automate_test.sh`.

Comment: At least for my GNU `cp`: `echo -e 'y\r' | cp -i -v 1.txt 2.txt` copies the files. Does not matter, looks like it only reads the first character, ignores the rest. But that's for GNU `cp`, OP may have different implementation.

Comment: @KamilCuk, ...you're relying on a GNU `echo` as well there. Better to use `printf` so its behavior is well-specified.

Comment: consider trying to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

Comment: @CharlesDuffy File is in UNIX format. Because when i executed "grep '^M'  your-file-name" it did not return any lines.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy "printf '%s\n' n y n | ./automate_test.sh" doesn't make any difference, output is same.

Comment: Complain to your OS vendor, then. If the copy of `cp` they provide doesn't read from stdin, it's violating the letter of the POSIX standard.

Comment: @MichałKrzysztofFeiler, ...if `expect` fixes the problem, that means that `cp` was reading from the TTY, not from stdin. The POSIX standard for `cp` **explicitly** requires it to read from stdin when `-i` is passed, so *if* using `expect` fixed the problem, that would mean whoever the OP's OS vendor is is shipping a noncompliant `cp`.

Comment: @matrixone, ...and who *is* your OS vendor, anyhow? We can't reproduce a problem with some specific vendor's `cp` if we don't know who that vendor is (and which version of their operating system you're running). If this is something like busybox `cp`, we'd want to know that too.

Comment: ...btw, I wonder if the upstream code is reading larger blocks than it needs, at least when given a non-TTY input feed. The spec requires `cp` to read from stdin, but it *doesn't* require each copy of `cp` to read only as much content as it's going to immediately use.

Comment: ...of course, the *other* possibility is that the problem isn't with the `cp -i`s, but something else you're doing from the same code before reaching them that's consuming stdin contrary to explanation. That would explain why nobody else here has been able to reproduce the problem, given only the content in the question itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am using MacOS Mojave version 10.14.3,  Shell script and input file is as it is, there is nothing before/after. I haven't tried using expect yet, will do that and let you know.

Comment: I can't reproduce your stated behavior on MacOS Catalina -- it doesn't print the `(y/n [n])` part of the prompt at all, *or* any `not overwritten` messages. Don't have a Mojave system to test on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to "talk" with interactive program using static file, consider letting 'cp' know which file to override with command line options:

- cp -f/--force, to force overwrite of existing file.
- cp -n/--no-clobber to leave existing file unmodified.

Remember that cp will not prompt for overwrite if the file does not exists, which will cause mismatch between questions and answers.